# RequireJS - Calling another property inside of a module.

Tags: javascript, function, properties, requirejs

So I really like to break my code up in to little reusable snippets, but I can't quite figure out how to do it in RequireJS. I've tried doing something like below, but it always returns undefined. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
return {
    mainFunction: function() {
       for(var i=0; i>5; i++) {
          this.helperFunction();
       }
    },

    helperFunction() {
        alert('help text');
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone runs into this same issue, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517904/self-reference-in-a-requirejs-module) answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by passing a function to define (this function is called a definition function). Inside the definition function:

1. Define the functions you'd like to use inside the module.
2. Make the definition function return an object with the functionality you'd like the module to expose. Here, in the object you are returning, you can call the functions defined in the previous step.

   ```
   define(function() {
       function foo() {
           return "Hello";
       };

       return {
           bar: function() {
               alert(foo());
           }
       }
   });
   ```